# Not exist in subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a temporary table which contains list of individual_ref  and i have another table called "Email" which contains Individual_ref, and email column in it. I want to find out those Individual_ref in temporary table doesnt exist in Email Table.

Below is my query which is not producing the result ism looking for.

```
select t.ind_ref from #temp_email t
where t.ind_ref  not in (SELECT EM.INDIVIDUAL_REF FROM EMAIL EM )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `INDIVIDUAL_REF` has null values so, in that case `NOT EXISTS` would do that trick :

```
select t.ind_ref
from #temp_email t
where not exists (select 1 from email e where e.INDIVIDUAL_REF = t.ind_ref);
```

`NOT IN` will fail if subquery return `null` value. So, you would have two ways one is filter subquery with `IS NOT NULL` or use `NOT EXISTS` directly.

Comment: thank you so much for your useful information. It work like a charm. Yes my subquery has null .

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that none of the value of Individual_Ref in Email table is null, because when we use not in the outer query to look up the non matching values from inner query, any value as null in inner query can results in entire result to be null.
My suggestion is to use where clause in inner query as ( where individual_ref is not null).

Comment: thank you so much for sharing the knowledge, i didnt knew it. I'm new to this.